# Inflection points and inverse functions

Tags: calculus, analysis

I was just wondering: Assume that a function $f$ is given, which is bijective, i.e. that $f^{-1}$ exists, and that $f^{-1}$ has an inflection point at $x_{\text{inf}}$. Does $f$ then have an inflection point at $x_{\text{inf}}$?

There might be some counter-examples, but I haven't found one yet (e.g. for $f^{-1} = x^{1/3}$, which has an inflection point at $0$, $f = x^3$ also has an inflection point at $0$).

Comment: You probably want to say that if $f$ has an inflexion point at $x_{inf}$, then $f^{-1}$ has an inflexion point at $f(x_{inf})$. Cf the counterexample on answer by @José Carlos Santos.

Comment: The answer (with the correction $f(x_{inf})$) is yes. An inflexion point on a _curve_ is a point where the curvature changes sign; as $f$ and $f^{-1}$ have symetric graphs, a change of sign in one graph is a change of sign in the other one. Unfortunately an inflection point can also be defined for a _function_ $f$, as a point where $f''$ is defined on an open interval around, has value $0$ on the point, $<0$ on one side and $>0$ on the other side. With this definition, $x^{1/3}$ has no inflection point because it has no derivative on $0$

Answer (score 0):

Take, for instance, $f(x)=x^3+1$. Then $f$ has an inflection point at $0$. However, the only inflection point of $f^{-1}$ is located at $1$.